# How to change the color in a image using PHP

Tags: php, image, gd, imagefilter

I have an image of a bar code, and I want to change the black color to any other color that is more colorful. How can I do it in PHP?

Comment: What format is the image? Does it have half-tones?

Comment: Not sure if this is the same question, but the answers might help you figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548534/php-replace-colour-within-image

Comment: The common format is jpeg.If the others, I think it can be changed to jpeg.Thanks your answer so quick!

Comment: @johnvip: does it have jpeg-caused artefacts?

Answer (score 5):

If your image is monochrome then you can use the [`imagefilter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) function:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('filename.jpg');
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 0, 255); // make it blue!
imagejpeg($image, 'filename.jpg');
```

Comment: great solution. i would also recommend using a gif or png for barcodes, as jpg can have artifacts that could cause the code not to scan. also make sure you test the barcodes as the colours you use may not register on all scanners. barcodes are generally black and white because it is high contrast (and cheap to print)

Answer (score 3):

combining code from this website and adding a little to my own, i have figured it out. enjoy.

```
function updateThumb($image, $newColor) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

    $w = imagesx($img);
    $h = imagesy($img);

    // Work through pixels
    for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++) {
        for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++) {
            // Apply new color + Alpha
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, $y));

            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
            imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $transparent);


            // Here, you would make your color transformation.
            $red_set=$newColor[0]/100*$rgb['red'];
            $green_set=$newColor[1]/100*$rgb['green'];
            $blue_set=$newColor[2]/100*$rgb['blue'];
            if($red_set>255)$red_set=255;
            if($green_set>255)$green_set=255;
            if($blue_set>255)$blue_set=255;

            $pixelColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, $red_set, $green_set, $blue_set, $rgb['alpha']);
            imagesetpixel ($img, $x, $y, $pixelColor);
        }
    }

    // Restore Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($img, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($img, true);

    return $img;
}

function makeThumb($path, $top, $bottom=FALSE) {
    $width = imagesx($top);
    $height = imagesy($top);

    $thumbHeight = $bottom != FALSE ? $height * 2 : $height;

    // Create Transparent PNG
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $thumbHeight);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $transparent);

    // Copy Top Image
    imagecopy($thumb, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

    // Copy Bottom Image
    if ($bottom != FALSE) {
        imagecopy($thumb, $bottom, 0, $height, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    }

    // Save Image with Alpha
    imageAlphaBlending($thumb, true);
    imageSaveAlpha($thumb, true);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($thumb, $path); // save image as png

}

$thumbTop = updateThumb('input/path', array(240,105,15));
```

Comment: Does this solution require the image to be a png?

Comment: Can you explain your solution a little bit?  Does this solution require the image to be a png?  Is the second parameter a hex vaue?  Does this create a new image and save it with the new colour, or does it not modify the existing image but only display it in a different colour to the current user?  Can you show a usage example?

Comment: just rgb using an array to store the rgb values. However, you could modify it to make rgba. Atm, I have it set to retain the alpha of the image your changing colors of. I originally used this to change colors of drawn characters and to more advanced to to change the iris of eyes to different colors.

Comment: Also I used a png for this, but you can probably use jpeg if you remove the alpha bits