# How to change color of a pic in destination?

Tags: php, javascript, rgb

How to change color of a pic in destination? suppose we have an image with two color(for example: black and white or brown and white) from a URL and want to 
display this image in our URL with different color.
Is there any function in PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: So the image will only have two colours?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548534/php-replace-colour-within-image

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to using the GD Library?

You can solve this by using a get function from the url

example url . domain.com/index.php?bgcolor=#234218

$bg_color = $_get[bgcolor];

Comment: I know the colors I want replace them with new colors