# How to erase a part of an image with background color?

Tags: php, gd

I have an image that contain from two color, background color and texts with other color, I want to erase a part of texts of it.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please show us an example of your code

Comment: I have no code, I have an image

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Replace colour within image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548534/php-replace-colour-within-image)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone All texts from one color, I can't replace color with color of background, Only I want to replace color of a part of image

Comment: We're going to need more to go on than this. Are you looking for php code to solve this problem? Do you have a sample image? Also, a sample of what you want the modified image to look like would be helpful as well.