# PHP background image colour

Tags: php, web-services, web

I am new to PHP and I am trying to remove colour(s) from a JPEG image on my server. Ideally, I want to be able to remove every colour in the image other than black or grey. I have posted code below of what I have done so far but it is not working (or it is working but I am not displaying it right). When I run the code, I get nothing on my screen. This is all the code in my index.php file so far:

```
$my_image='Photo.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($my_image); 
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $color);
imagejpeg($my_image, null);
```

Can someone tell me how to fix my problem please? Thank you!

Comment: **$output_file_name** has not been created.

Comment: @Wolfram Oh sorry I forgot to edit that. Thank you!. I have edited it. I have simply used $my_image in hopes that it would overwrite the old image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

- `imagecreatefromstring` doesn't load images from a file, but takes a string that contains *image data*. [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) will load from a file.
- To display a page as an image, you have to send the proper header. For example, `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`
- `imagejpeg` outputs an image. The return value is just whether or not it succeeded. Take a look at [the example in the documentation.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

---

To delete every color that isn't black/gray/white, you probably have to check each pixel individually, like so:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('file.jpg');

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($image); $x++) {
   for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($image); $y++) {
      $pixel = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
      if(!isGray($pixel))
         imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, $white);
   }
}

imagejpeg($image);

function isGray($pix) {
   $r = ($pix >> 16) & 0xFF;
   $g = ($pix >> 8) & 0xFF;
   $b = $pix & 0xFF;
   return ($r == $g) && ($g == $b);
}
?>
```

Since you're using JPGs, I can't think of an easier way. The artifacts the JPG compression process creates disrupt solid colors, so simply checking for, e.g., red or blue wouldn't work.

The code was adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607796/246847.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have done what you suggested but am getting the error: The image "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/testing/index.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors". Do you know why this is happening? I have edited my code. Thanks again, I really appreciate it

Comment: Can you add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the file, comment out the `header`, and see if it prints any errors?

Comment: Tom, I believe I have it working but I must apologize for this is not the effect I wanted. I wanted the code to remove colours WITHIN the image itself and not the background of the page. So I apologize. I will accept your answer anyway but do you by any chance know how to do what I just explained? It would really mean a lot. Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. It would help if you posted two versions of an image, one original and one edited to show what result you want.

Comment: For example, suppose I have a picture of a red sweater. I want to remove the red colour from this sweater and make it transparent or white.

Comment: This is what I was looking for but this also removes numbers I had in the image as well for some reason? SO I want to ask you for one last favour, I apologize for the hassle but how could the code be modified to only remove the color red. Thank you so much, last question I promise

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to change the condition in the loop to only replace the colors you want. Plus, you haven't provided enough information for me to do it for you. For instance, how do you define "red"? Is it `rgb(255,0,0)`? I guarantee that if you have a JPG, there will be artifacts that are *red*, but not `rgb(255,0,0)`. So maybe any color where the red value is greater than the blue or green? But that includes orange and violet. This is all I can do with the information available.