# Replace colour tones with HSL + GD?

Tags: php, colors, gd, hsl

We are working with a base image that has three tones of blue (`#645591`, `#6B90CA` and `#7BC8EF`) with one user-chosen colour that will replace the first blue value (the base) and it will generate two tones for the extra two colours to be replaced.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608505/201877) that is very efficient and useful, but the question is **how to calculate the difference between one colour and the other, so I can reuse that difference in a totally different colour?**

First, I thought I could get the RGB difference and just add it to the new colour, which was ver naive of me.

Then, after some research, it seems that HSL is the way to go, so I calculated the difference between the base blue (the first one) and the next two values, that way I could certainy select another value and add the difference, right? Well... turns out it doesn't:

[image]

The next and current try is to leave the Hue value alone and add the original difference for the Saturation and Light values, the result is pretty good, but I'm not sure it would work for different colours.

[image]

- Is there a way to preserve the tones while the colours change?
- Is HSL the way to go?
- I have a feeling about converting it to greyscale and then colourizing it from there, is that correct?

---

Here's the code, I've made it with CSS to test the concept, but the tools are PHP+GD.

```
<style>
span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
.c1{
  background: #645591;
  /* hsl(255, 26%, 45%) */
}
.c2{
  background: #6B90CA;
  /* hsl(217, 47%, 61%) */
}
.c3{
  background: #7BC8EF;
  /* hsl(200, 78%, 71%) */
}
.r1{
  background: hsl(50, 35%, 24%);
}
.r2{
  background: hsl(12, 56%, 40%);
}
.r3{
  background: hsl(355, 87%, 50%);
}
/* Preserving the Hue values turns out to be pretty good */
.z1{
  background: hsl(355, 35%, 24%);
}
.z2{
  background: hsl(355, 56%, 40%);
}
.z3{
  background: hsl(355, 87%, 50%);
}
</style>
<span class="c3"></span>
<span class="c2"></span>
<span class="c1"></span>
<span style="width: 50px;"></span>
<span class="r3"></span>
<span class="r2"></span>
<span class="r1"></span>
<span style="width: 50px;"></span>
<span class="z3"></span>
<span class="z2"></span>
<span class="z1"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there really a point in calculating the differences between colors 1, 2 and 3 on the fly? If I look at your original, you're doing: basecolor, basecolor a bit less saturated, a lot darker, and then a bit less saturated also and a lot darker also.

Why not just use the same formula for each transformation and let the user pick a base color out of a given palette

You can then pick say 32 base colors for your own tests and generate the 3-colors set for each of them, to see how well it works.

If that does not work so well, then, you might want to Google on "perception of color" or something similar. We do not perceive changes in darkness (among other qualities if I remember correctly) the same way for all colors.

You might also wanna consider going all CSS or CSS+PHP or LessCss or CSS+Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Of course I can make my own tests, but what I'm looking for is the right way to do it. Also, the images might be a lot complicated, so going with CSS, Less or Javascript is not an options since they *must* be generated with GD.